# everytime i insert a row into a table with the help of http post from my android app, two rows get inserted

Tags: android, http-post

Android part

```
final ProgressDialog p = new ProgressDialog(arg0.getContext()).show(arg0.getContext(),"Waiting for Server", "Accessing Server");
        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                   try{

                     httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                     httppost= new HttpPost("http://www.ng.in/m/z.php"); 

                     nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("z_101","3"));
                     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname",info));
                     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bill",""+bill));
                     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                     //Execute HTTP Post Request
                     response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

                     ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                     final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                     System.out.println("Response : " + response);
                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                p.dismiss();
                              pay.append(response);   
                            }

                           });


                 }catch(Exception e){

                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
            }
        };

        thread.start();
```

Php Code:-

```
 <?php
require "connect.inc.php";
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$bill=(int)$_POST['bill'];
$z_101=(int)$_POST['z_101'];
$rest="z";
$query1="insert into mc_log (uname,rname,bill) values ('$uname','$rest','$bill')";
$result1=mysql_query($query1);
?>
```

Everytime i run it two rows with the same values are getting inserted into the mc_log table. The mc_log table has two more columns i) id which is primary key and auto_increamented  ii) time which is by  default systime.

Answer (score 2):

This code looks doubled:

```
//Execute HTTP Post Request
response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
fnal String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

You are calling `execute()` two times, that is the problem...